# Constrained Polynomial Regression - Fixed Maximum

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to fit some kind of polynomical regression to a car engine performance curve. I know that the relationship between the studied two variables is not linear and should follow a quadratic function (performance v.s output power).

[Power vs Performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4alR.jpg)

*`-14e-05{x^2}+0,009{x}+0,31545`*

Also I know that the derivative of the function that relates this two variables should be 0 (absolute maximum) when the engine is delivering the maximum power.

The problem comes when after fitting my curve I make the derivative of the function obtained through the polynomial regression I get has the maximum  beyond the maximum real power output of the engine (under safety limits)

I have been looking for topics doing the same but I have found only issues related with the sum of the coefficients should be under certain value.

Any ideas to implement this in R?

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data, or if it small add it to your question?

Comment: Dear James, the data is huge (around 44000 values) and relatively (private). I have add a plot with the physical constrains that I mentioned, basically if a fit a polynomial regression to this values I got the following function:

-14e-05x^2+0,009x+0,31545 that has the maximum performance value around 67kW which would be physically impossible due to the control restrictions (maximum outpower allowed = 50kW)